# Can I change the Styles from a Row if I make a mouseover in a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, styles, mouseover

I use a ListView and I want if I make a mouseover about the Item I get a other color and a other font size and font color...the other color works but can I do two or more styleschanges in the mouseover?

Here my ListView:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView" OnItemCommand="myListView_ItemCommand"
                       OnSelectedIndexChanging="myListView_SelectedIndexChanging" 
            > 


            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server" class="tablelistview" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr class="TableClass">
                    <th align="left" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLastname" runat="server" CssClass="MyLink" OnClick="lnkLastnameSort_Click" >Nachname</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgLastnameAsc" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/asc.png" />
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgLastnameDESC" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/desc.png" Visible="false" />
                    </th>

                    <th class="TableColumns"  runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFirstname" CssClass="MyLink" runat="server" OnClick="lnkFirstnameSort_Click" >Vorname</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgFirstnameAsc" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/asc.png" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgFirstnameDesc" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/desc.png" Visible="false" />
                    </th>

                    <th class="TableColumns" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="lnkPhone" runat="server" >Telefon</asp:Label></th>

                    <th class="TableColumns" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDepartment" CssClass="MyLink" runat="server" OnClick="lnkDepartmentSort_Click">Abteilung</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgDepartmentAsc" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/asc.png" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgDepartmentDesc" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/desc.png" Visible="false" />
                    </th>

                    <th class="TableColumns" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkemail" CssClass="MyLink" runat="server" OnClick="lnkMailSort_Click" >Email</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgMailAsc" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/asc.png" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgMailDesc" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/desc.png" Visible="false" />
                    </th> 

                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr> 
            </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="TableClassO" runat="server" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#838383'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'" titel="Auswahl"> 
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="abteilung" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label7" Text='<%# Eval("Abteilung") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:ImageButton Width="15" Height="15" CssClass="MyLink" CommandName="mailto"  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label8" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/Email.ico" runat="server" />

                 <asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="mailto" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" ToolTip="Öffnet Outlook" /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>
            </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr class="TableClassO" runat="server" style="background-color:#E5EDF5;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#838383'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#E5EDF5'" titel="Auswahl"> 
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="abteilung" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label7" Text='<%# Eval("Abteilung") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:ImageButton Width="15" Height="15" CssClass="MyLink" CommandName="mailto"  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label8" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/Email.ico" runat="server" />

                 <asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="mailto" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" ToolTip="Öffnet Outlook" /></td>
                 <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>
            </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                 <div><h4>Es wurden keine Einträge gefunden</h4></div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: You should be able to add css for the element :hover that would change when you hover over the element. Otherwise you can do anything you want in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can like

```
<tr class="TableClassO" runat="server" 
  onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#838383'; this.style.color='some-color';" 
  onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'; this.style.color='some-other-color'" titel="Auswahl">
```

for font color you can use `this.style.color` and for font-size `this.style.fontSize`

but it will easy if you create a css-rule class for :hover like

```
tr.TableClassO:hover { your_css_rule_here ;} 
// It will run when mouse over on tr, then you dont need to use js events.
```

Comment: and for font-size and font-color ? this.style.font-size='' ?

Comment: for font-color and font-size these are `color` and `fontSize`

Comment: putting the styles in each TR is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: I know how I can do this with the CSS file if I make a mouseover but I don't know how I can do this if I make a mouseout :(

Comment: @Tarasov: with a mouseout, you simply declare the class, e.g: .myclass:hover {/\* styles when hovering */} and .myclass {/\* styles when not hovering e.g. mouse-out */}

Comment: @Tarasov: the styles for hover will only be active during the mouse hover, and as soon as the user takes away the mouse the style will automatically default to the style before the hover took place.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, easily, by doing this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .TableClass:hover {
        background-color: red;
        font-family: courier new;
    }
</style>
```

The above is just an example. You just replace "TableClass" with the name of the row's class.

The style section is usually put in the head section, or is linked from an external file.

For further reference, look here at the W3school site:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

**Also, I would just like to state, that you should use CSS over anything else, because it is much more native to the browsers (and more compatible cross-browser).**

Another thing. By putting your styles in each of the TR elements is a mess. By using CSS you are placing it in one location and therefore can change just that one location when you want to modify the styles slightly. With your current solution, you would have to change it on every row, and the size of your pages will massively bloat!

SR